# Different design between emulator / cellphone and notebook

Tags: html, css

I tried to write a design like a table and it should be responsive. I use vh and vw for height and width. the design should have 5 rows and 3 cols. When I test the design with the first two rows it looks nice on cellphone and notebook. When I add a third row I get a destroyed design on notebook. On the cellphone it looks great.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "de">
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta charset = "utf-8">
        <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "./css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id = 'reihe1'>
            <div id = 'spalte1reihe1'>
            </div>
            <div id = 'spalte2reihe1'>
            </div>
            <div id = 'spalte3reihe1'>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id = 'reihe2'>
            <div id = 'spalte1reihe2'>
            </div>
            <div id = 'spalte2reihe2'>
            </div>
            <div id = 'spalte3reihe2'>
            </div>          
        </div>
        <div id = 'reihe3'>
            <div id = 'spalte1reihe3'>
            </div>
            <div id = 'spalte2reihe3'>
            </div>
            <div id = 'spalte3reihe3'>
            </div>          
        </div>
        <div id = 'reihe4'>
            <div id = 'spalte1reihe4'>
            </div>
            <div id = 'spalte2reihe4'>
            </div>
            <div id = 'spalte3reihe4'>
            </div>          
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
* { box-sizing: border-box;}

body {
    background-color: #3C3C3B; /* Dunkel Grau */
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

/* Willkommenseite */

#spalte1reihe1 {
    width: 25vw;
    height: 25vh;
    float: left;
    background-color: #ECECEC; /* Grau */
}

#spalte2reihe1 {
    width: 48vw;
    height: 25vh;   
    float: left;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

#spalte3reihe1 {
    width: 25vw;
    float: left;
    height: 25vh;
    background-color: #ECECEC; /* Grau */
}

#spalte1reihe2 {
    width: 25vw;
    height: 19vh;
    float: left;
    background-color: #2DAB66; /* Grün */
}

#spalte2reihe2 {
    width: 48vw;
    height: 19vh;   
    float: left;
    background-color: #ECECEC; /* Grau */
}

#spalte3reihe2 {
    width: 25vw;
    float: left;
    height: 19vh;
    background-color: #2DAB66; /* Grün */
}

#spalte1reihe3 {
    width: 25vw;
    height: 19vh;
    float: left;
    background-color: #ECECEC; /* Grün */
}

#spalte2reihe3 {
    width: 48vw;
    height: 19vh;
    float: left;
    background-color: #ffffff; /* Grün */
}

#spalte3reihe3 {
    width: 25vw;
    height: 19vh;
    float: left;
    background-color: #ECECEC; /* Grün */
}

#spalte1reihe4 {
    width: 25vw;
    height: 25vh;
    float: left;
    background-color: #ECECEC; /* Grau */
}

#spalte2reihe4 {
    width: 48vw;
    height: 25vh;   
    float: left;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

#spalte3reihe4 {
    width: 25vw;
    float: left;
    height: 25vh;
    background-color: #ECECEC; /* Grau */
}
```

I validate the Code i don't get any Errors. So i don't know where is the mistake.
http://www.benwillgruber.com/stefanseite/test/index.php you can check the site to see the Problem.

Thx for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
body {
  width: 100vw;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

> Currently all browsers but Firefox incorrectly consider 100vw to be the entire page width, including vertical scroll bar, which can cause a horizontal scroll bar when overflow: auto is set.

Comment: Actually it is not a mistake, browser support for vh/vw units is not that good yet.